# Getting this error when I try to start npm

Tags: reactjs

How to solve this error?

```
PS G:\ReactJs\ReactApplicationRedux\ReactApplicationRedux> start npm
PS G:\ReactJs\ReactApplicationRedux\ReactApplicationRedux> npm start

> myapp@0.1.0 start G:\ReactJs\ReactApplicationRedux\ReactApplicationRedux
> PORT=3006 react-scripts start

'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 start: `PORT=3006 react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Manjunathan S\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-28T17_00_34_422Z-debug.log
PS G:\ReactJs\ReactApplicationRedux\ReactApplicationRedux> mpm start
mpm : The term 'mpm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
+ mpm start
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mpm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
PS G:\ReactJs\ReactApplicationRedux\ReactApplicationRedux> npm start

> myapp@0.1.0 start G:\ReactJs\ReactApplicationRedux\ReactApplicationRedux
> PORT=3006 react-scripts start

'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 start: `PORT=3006 react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Manjunathan S\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-28T17_00_54_168Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json you need to make sure

Change

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

**Linux:**

```
"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"
```

or

```
"start": "export PORT=3006 react-scripts start"
```

**Windows:**

```
"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"
```

Also **the best way** in my opinion and the one I use is to create a file called

**.env.development**

at the same level of your **package.json**

and add

```
PORT=3006
```

to your file.

**Notice that you can create different .env files like .env.production etc... or simply .env**

[Environment Variables using .env file in REACT](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)